# In C# .net how to licensing using RSA and license provider class?

Tags: c#, .net, security

I want to provide license to the simple console application.
I used RSACrypttoServiceProvider class to encrypt and decrypt.
I also want to use LicFileLicenseProvider class to grant license for my application.
how to inherit LicFileLicenseProvider class and use it?
Namespase.classname.lic file contains text - "Namespase.classname is a licensed component." - how to modify this ? if I modify this and use Validate OR isvalid method it will return null and false results respectively.
please suggest solution.

Answer (score 1):

Look at http://www.drdobbs.com/184416695;jsessionid=4JVBZKOX0D5NRQE1GHRSKH4ATMY32JVN. Search for `DerivedLicenseProvider`. Is if not what you are looking for? Another article http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_framework/licensing/article.php/c5469 don't give you a direct example about inheritance of `LicFileLicenseProvider`, but if you not yet know it, you should read it.