# RSA signing in C#

Tags: c#, rsa, sign, pem

I need to make a software activation mechanism.
So i ended up with this scheme:
App creates a unique id, based on computer's hardware.
Buyer emails this id to me.
I sign it with my private key and i send back the signed string.
App verifies string (decodes it with contained public key and compares it with hardware id).

So far i am done with hardware id and i have created the keys (1024bit) with openssl, that's two files private.pem and public.pem.

I worked with some code provided by msdn, but i don't quite understand how to import my keys into RSA algorithm.
Some of the code follows, any help will be appreciated...

```
        try
        {
            // Create a UnicodeEncoder to convert between byte array and string.
            ASCIIEncoding ByteConverter = new ASCIIEncoding();

            string dataString = CompID.Text;

            // Create byte arrays to hold original, encrypted, and decrypted data. 
            byte[] originalData = ByteConverter.GetBytes(dataString);
            byte[] signedData;

            // Create a new instance of the RSACryptoServiceProvider class  
            // and automatically create a new key-pair.
            RSACryptoServiceProvider RSAalg = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();

            // Export the key information to an RSAParameters object. 
            // You must pass true to export the private key for signing. 
            // However, you do not need to export the private key 
            // for verification.
            RSAParameters Key = RSAalg.ExportParameters(true);

            // Hash and sign the data.
            signedData = HashAndSignBytes(originalData, Key);
            ActCode.Text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(signedData, 0, signedData.Length);                

            // Verify the data and display the result to the  
            // console. 
            if (VerifySignedHash(originalData, signedData, Key))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("The data was verified.");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("The data does not match the signature.");
            }

        }
        catch (ArgumentNullException)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("The data was not signed or verified");

        }
```

The methods:

```
    public static byte[] HashAndSignBytes(byte[] DataToSign, RSAParameters Key)
    {
        try
        {
            // Create a new instance of RSACryptoServiceProvider using the  
            // key from RSAParameters.  
            RSACryptoServiceProvider RSAalg = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();

            RSAalg.ImportParameters(Key);

            // Hash and sign the data. Pass a new instance of SHA1CryptoServiceProvider 
            // to specify the use of SHA1 for hashing. 
            return RSAalg.SignData(DataToSign, new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider());
        }
        catch (CryptographicException e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message);

            return null;
        }
    }

    public static bool VerifySignedHash(byte[] DataToVerify, byte[] SignedData, RSAParameters Key)
    {
        try
        {
            // Create a new instance of RSACryptoServiceProvider using the  
            // key from RSAParameters.
            RSACryptoServiceProvider RSAalg = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();

            RSAalg.ImportParameters(Key);

            // Verify the data using the signature.  Pass a new instance of SHA1CryptoServiceProvider 
            // to specify the use of SHA1 for hashing. 
            return RSAalg.VerifyData(DataToVerify, new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider(), SignedData);

        }
        catch (CryptographicException e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message);

            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: when you generate the hash, you will want to also include something from the product like name and/or version so they key validates only for that product.  also maybe add something about them they cannot see in your code like email, name etc to make it harder to create a key gen.

Comment: Answered already? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3084440/in-c-sharp-net-how-to-licensing-using-rsa-and-license-provider-class

Comment: @plinth the answer you noted has one article with broken links and one with irellevant content

Comment: @Plutonix thanks for the advice, i'll keep it in mind