# RSA signing in C# for licensing

Tags: c#, rsa, sign, rsacryptoserviceprovider

(Approach #2)
I need to make a software activation mechanism. So i ended up with this scheme: App creates a unique id, based on computer's hardware. Buyer emails this id to me. I sign it with my private key and i send back the signed string. App verifies string (decodes it with contained public key and compares it with hardware id).

So far i am done with hardware id and i have created the keys (1024bit) with openssl, that's two files private.pem and public.pem.

I tried to apply the solution described in http://www.christian-etter.de/?p=771
but verification always fails.

The code:

```
    private void Generate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        byte[] SignedData;
        byte[] UnsignedData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(CompID.Text);

        using (RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
        {
            rsa.PersistKeyInCsp = false;
            rsa.LoadPrivateKeyPEM(PrivateKey.Text);
            using (SHA1CryptoServiceProvider sha1 = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider())
                SignedData = rsa.SignData(UnsignedData, sha1);
            ActCode.Text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(SignedData, 0, SignedData.Length);
        }
    }

    //--------------------------------------------------------------------

    private void Verify_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        byte[] UnsignedData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(CompID.Text);
        byte[] SignedData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(ActCode.Text);
        bool VerifOK;

        using (RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
        {
            rsa.PersistKeyInCsp = false;
            rsa.LoadPublicKeyPEM(PublicKey.Text);
            using (SHA1CryptoServiceProvider sha1 = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider())
                VerifOK = rsa.VerifyData(UnsignedData, sha1, SignedData);
        }
        if (VerifOK) verif.Text = "verification ok";
        else verif.Text = "verification error";
    }
```

Comment: Didn't look at this in depth, but the fact that your code seems cavalier about switching to UTF-8 or storing in a textbox means that you're probably unknowingly altering the bytes. Going back and forth from a string to `byte[]` is dangerous unless you're very careful. Try and keep the data as `byte[]` if at all possible.

Comment: Not all byte sequences are valid UTF-8 encodings. Use Base64 encoding via `Convert.To/FromBase64String` to handle the `SignedData`.

Comment: @mikez Thank you very much! I missed that. That did the trick!

Comment: @LynnCrumbling Thanks for pointing to the right direction.

Comment: I will add it as an answer and you can mark it as accepted.

Comment: possible duplicate of [RSA signing in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28096261/rsa-signing-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @mikez Nice job with this. (+1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are treating some arbitrary bytes as a UTF-8 encoded string (`SignedData`) This is incorrect because not all byte sequences are valid. I suspect the encoder is throwing out the invalid bytes, causing verification to fail. You should use Base64 encoding to preserve the binary data in a string format without losing anything. So this:

```
using (SHA1CryptoServiceProvider sha1 = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider())
    SignedData = rsa.SignData(UnsignedData, sha1);
ActCode.Text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(SignedData, 0, SignedData.Length);
```

becomes

```
using (SHA1CryptoServiceProvider sha1 = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider())
    SignedData = rsa.SignData(UnsignedData, sha1);
ActCode.Text = Convert.ToBase64String(SignedData);
```

Likewise during verification you need to use `Convert.FromBase64String` to get the `SignedData`. It is OK to use UTF-8 for the CompID because it is string data that you need converted to a binary form for signing.