# c#, how to store and check a generated license key?

Tags: c#, ssl, encryption, cryptography

I read quite a lot about RSA, Encryption, License Keys etc. but I'm still confused.

We have a web application which can be installed locally by customers (they usually should choose the SaaS version, but some might not want it)
The app has different modules etc. (pretty standard)

Our backend stores the customer data and the licenses/bought modules and is accessible via SSL.

The "client" will periodically check if the issued license is still valid.

What's quite unclear to me is how do I store the license key and/or data like "how long is the license valid"

My thoughts so far:

- just save it in a table (cleartext) and the periodic license check ensures the validity of the license even when the user tampers with the data in the database. (user might have access to parts he shouldn't for a short time)
- Encrypt it and save it in a table. This would mean that I either

  - use a shared key
  - use a private/public key: So either have to decrypt with the public key (on the client) or send it to the Backend to decrypt and send it back to the client.

I just have the feeling encrypting the whole thing is an overhead.

I'm no expert in security and/or cryptography.

So my question is

- What is the best practise when checking/storing licenses (and its data)?

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

I removed the question "Is the SSL enough?" in the last paragraph because I realized this is a different topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume, you have your license file locally and the check happens client side only? You could do the following:

1. Generate a license file on the server (whatever format you want, can even be plaintext)
2. Sign this file with your private key (no need for encryption, just attach the signature)
3. Include your license, signature and public key with your app (or make them downloadable to be able to update/revoke licenses)
4. When checking the license file, just check the signature with your public key. If the client tampered with the license file, the signature won't validate.

Of course, you'll have to somehow protect your deployed public key, so the client cannot replace it with it's own and create it's own license file.

With XML you could for instance use [XML Signature](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229745(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thanks, that means creating my "own" implementation of an private/public key encryption (RSA for example), correct?
Or do I need some certificate (like X509)?

Comment: Or would/could/should I use my SSL certificate which is installed on the Backend?

Comment: What do you mean by "your own implementation"? Of course .net includes classes for pk-encryption/signing (for instance RSA) but you'll need a key pair to use them. See for instance [this question][http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28099187/rsa-signing-in-c-sharp-for-licensing]

Comment: that's what I meant in a rather clumsy way ;)

Could I use my SSL certificate with its public/private keys for this?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know if or how you could export the keys from your certificate to be usable in such a scenario